# What exactly means software accessable registers, while adding custom IP in Xilinx?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

Can some one provide me some in-depth understanding what exactly software accessible registers, means?
What I understand is that since these registers are memory mapped so you can send in data through it which can be accessed by processor /custom ip /ram as per needed.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

I will grateful if someone can correct my understanding!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Software accessible registers would mean that the software running on the CPU would be able to read and write to the registers located inside the custom IP.

The software will be using memory instructions to read and write to the register.  Please note, that all xfers are initiated by the software.  So if you would like the custome ip to send some data via the registers, then you have inform the software/cpu that the data is available.  This can be done via an interrupt or if you setup the software to monitor the register periodically.

If you clarify what you are trying to achieve and the type of cpu that you are using, then you may get a clearer answer.

Comment: Dear Shparekh, Many thanks for the replyI want to send a sequence (well shorted data) to FPGA via ethernet and write it over to the DDR2 memory. Now inbuilt powerpc on fpga should use Block ram (in cascade) as fifo and send the data to my custom ip. I hope i could explain you my problem.

Comment: Check out the manual on how you can setup dma xfers.  Doing a quick search on google - brought up [Xilinx XAPP1126](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xilinx.com%2Fsupport%2Fdocumentation%2Fapplication_notes%2Fxapp1126.pdf&ei=HUgFUu2TIsGX2QXch4GADQ&usg=AFQjCNFsqkrDLqrkcysnKnrc2-DwhjKOVQ&sig2=zKKBqlNFz_PyioyKKLJ4dg&bvm=bv.50500085,d.b2I&cad=rjt).  I suspect you are using Xilinx FPGA.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind attention.Yes you are correct. I am using Virtex-5 Minimodule FPGA from Xilinx. I donot want to connect my Custom Ip using any fast LL. I want to use PLB for DMA transfer.